# Issues removing markers from worldmap on node-red

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I have multiple markers with different name on my worldmap running on node-red. I can delete them one by one with the following code:

markers:

```
1. msg.payload = {"name":"Delivery-2","lat":55.87782,"lon":-4.32508};
return msg;

2. msg.payload = {"icon":"car", "name":"Delivery-3","lat":55.87782,"lon":-4.32308};
return msg;
```

delete Marker code:

```
msg.payload = {"name":"Delivery-3", "deleted": true};
return msg;
```

I am searching for the best way to delete all the markers with a single code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add your markers to a named layer, you can use the `clear` command to remove all markers in one go.

e.g.

```
msg.payload = {"layer": "foo", "name":"Delivery-2","lat":55.87782,"lon":-4.32508};
```

Then clear with:

```
msg.payload = {"command":{"clear":"foo"}}
```